# Allowing non-sysadmin users to see SQL Server execution plans

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, permissions, execution-plan

Is this possible ? On SQL Server 2012+, grant access to a non sysadmin user to see the execution plans ? And can this be done for selected databases only ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer generated from question comments*</sub>

---

Yes this is possible. See:

- [Syntax for Granting, Denying, and Revoking the `SHOWPLAN` Permission](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175117(v=sql.105).aspx)<sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup>
- [Showplan Security](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189602(v=SQL.110).aspx)<sup>2</sup>
- [`SHOWPLAN` Permission and Transact-SQL Batches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178086(v=sql.110).aspx)<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Contributed by *[Mark Sinkinson](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/33638/mark-sinkinson)*
<sup>2</sup> Contributed by *[Aaron Bertrand♦](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand)*